# Como mostrar una imagen cuando pasamos de activity en un ListView

Tags: java, android-studio

estoy teniendo unos problemas para mostrar una imagen cuando hago click en una lista y paso de actividad. El problema lo tengo creo, en el **MainActivity.java** en la linea `intent.getParcelableExtra("foto", datos.getFoto());` creo que le estoy pasando mal los parametros para que cargue la foto. 
Luego lo envió todo a la segunda actividad **SecondActivity.java** donde intento cargar la foto para mostrar, pero no se carga en ningún momento.

No se que puedo estar haciendo mal para que no muestre la imagen.

**Archivo - MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         ListView lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_lista);
        final ArrayList<Datos> arraydatos = new ArrayList<>();
        Datos datos;

        //Introduzco los datos
        datos = new Datos(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.foto1), "Foto numero 1", "Imagen de tipo png", 1);
        arraydatos.add(datos);
        datos = new Datos(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.foto2), "Foto numero 2", "Imagen de tipo png", 2);
        arraydatos.add(datos);


        //Creo el adapter personalizado
         AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(this, arraydatos);


        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Log.d("Error", listados.toString());
                Datos datos = arraydatos.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);


                // intent.putExtra("id", lista.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

                intent.putExtra("id", datos.getId());
                intent.getParcelableExtra("foto", datos.getFoto());
                intent.putExtra("nombre", datos.getNombre());
                intent.putExtra("info", datos.getInfo());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });




        //Lo aplico
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**Archivo - SecondActivity.java**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        //private Toolbar mToolbar;
        private TextView textView;
        private ImageView flag;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

            //Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
            ImageView flag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_fotoMostrar);
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);


            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(bundle != null){

                textView.setText(bundle.getString("nombre"));
                flag.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) bundle.getParcelable("foto"));



    /*
                mToolbar.setTitle(bundle.getString("id"));
                if(mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                    flag.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.foto1));
                   // flag.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondActivity.this, R.drawable.foto1));
                }
                */
            }


        }
    }
```

**Archivo - Datos.java**

```
public class Datos {
    //Declaramos los siguientes atributos
    protected Drawable foto;
    protected String nombre;
    protected String info;
    protected long id;

    //Método constructor de la clase
    public Datos(Drawable foto, String nombre, String info, long id){
        this.foto = foto;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.info = info;
        this.id = id;
    }


    // Métodos get and set

    //Método get obtiene datos
    public Drawable getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    //Método set asigna o inicializa los datos
    public void setFoto(Drawable foto){
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getInfo(){
        return info;
    }
    public void setInfo(String info){
        this.info = info;
    }
    public long getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

---

> ### **AdapterDatos.class**

```
public class AdapterDatos extends BaseAdapter {

    //Declaramos los siguiente
    protected Activity activity;
    //Dentro del ArrayList colocamos la clase Datos
    protected ArrayList<Datos> items;

    //Metodo contructor de la clase
    public AdapterDatos(Activity activity, ArrayList<Datos> items){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //Obtenemos el tamaño de los items
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        //Obtenemos la posicion del items
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return items.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Generamos una converView por motivos de eficiencia
        View v = convertView;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inf.inflate(R.layout.itemlista, null);
        }

        //Creamos un objecto de la clase Datos
        Datos datos = items.get(position);

            //Rellenamos la fotografia
            ImageView foto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView_Foto);
            foto.setImageDrawable(datos.getFoto());


            //Rellenamos el nombre
            TextView nombre = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView_Nombre);
            nombre.setText(datos.getNombre());

            //Rellenamos la info
            TextView info = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView_Info);
            info.setText(datos.getInfo());

        //Retornamos la vista
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que haria es cambiar la variable:

```
protected Drawable foto;
```

A tipo string y ahí guardar el nombre de la foto:

```
protected String foto;
```

Con esto a la hora de pasar al intent la información deberás cambiar la forma de pasar la foto a esta:

```
intent.putExtra("foto", datos.getFoto()); //datos.getFoto() es el nombre de la foto
```

Ahora en `SecondActivity` deberás crear una variable `String` para recojer el nombre de la foto:

```
String fotoNombre = bundle.getString("foto");
```

Ya obtenido el nombre el siguiente paso a hacer es conseguir el

> "resourceId"

de la foto, sería el identificador único, y esto se haría:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(fotoNombre , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

El objeto ImageView tiene un método par asignarle una imagen pasándole su identificador único

> setImageResource(int redId)

Ya la último sería asignar a flag el recurso:

```
flag.setImageResource(resID);
```

En Adpter class en el constructor le tendrás que pasare el contexto de la actividad principal:

```
protected ArrayList<Datos> items;
protected Context contexto;
    //Metodo contructor de la clase
    public AdapterDatos(Activity activity, ArrayList<Datos> items,Context contexto){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
        this.contexto = contexto;
    }
```

Y en el método getView:

```
Datos datos = items.get(position);

    //Rellenamos la fotografia
    ImageView foto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView_Foto);
    String fotoNombre = bundle.getString("foto");
    int resID = contexto.getResources().getIdentifier(fotoNombre , "drawable", getPackageName());
    foto.setImageResource(resID);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu Rápida respuesta, pero se me olvido mencionar un trozo de código en la pregunta que realice. Se me olvido añadir la clase AdapterDatos.class ; En la linea foto.setImageDrawable(datos.getFoto()); debería de cambiar este parámetro como mencionas a String. ¿Que es lo que debería reemplazar?. Gracias de Antemano Sharaz

Comment: me podrías enseñar la clase adaptador?

Comment: Lo tienes, añadido arriba en la pregunta. Si miras hacia abajo veras en Negrita AdapterDatos.class

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta con el adaptador añadido, espero que te sirva

Comment: He realizado los cambios que me decías, pero no se porque todavía no funciona. He convertido como mencionabas en String la foto. Pero al final en el parámetro de AdapterDatos.class que mencionas que le añada  Context contexto; no se que debo de pasarle en el archivo MainActivity.java ya que menciono ahi la clase AdapterDatos. Ademas no puedo realizar un bundle dentro del método getView:, tambien me da fallo.

Comment: En el MainActivity tienes que pasarle "getContext()"